# Add 2 query percentage into one query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables, and 2 queries.

1. tbl_stud - for student information including, lrn (the stud_no), and stud_name
2. tbl_written - there are 5 columns (one, two, three, four, five) for 5 activities (one activity, one column each) that includes the stud_name as its primary key
3. tbl_perf - the same with tbl_written, 5 columns (one, two, three, four, five) for 5 activities (one activity, one column each)

then 2 queries,

1. q_totalper - computes the total 5 activities and its percentage (20%) of the tbl_written

code: `SELECT stud_name, (one + two + three+four+five) AS Total_written, (( one + two + three+four+five)/60 * .2)*100 AS percentage_written FROM tbl_written`

2. q_total - computes the total 5 activities and its percentage (20%) of the tbl_perf my problem is to combine the percentages of the 2 queries

code: `SELECT stud_name, (one + two + three+four+five) AS Total_perf, (( one + two + three+four+five)/60 * .2)*100 AS percentage_perf FROM tbl_perf;`

Tried many SQL's I've searched on the internet.

Shown in the picture that these are two queries. I need to combine the percentage_perf and percentage_written to become the new query `quarter_grade`

My sql code is below...

```
SELECT stud_name, percentage_perf
FROM q_totalper
union
SELECT stud_name, percentage_written
FROM q_total
```

When I run this code, it always asks me... the parameter value of the percentage_perf

But I want to have a result like this:

```
stud_name                percentage_written     percentage_perf    quarter_grade
A*******************     14.3333333333333     11.6666666666667   26.0000003
A*****                   13     10.6666666666667   23.666667`
```

Currently doing grading system.

Thanks for those who will help me!

BTW, the computed percentage_written is from q_totalper the same as with percentage_perf is from q_total

Will apply the sql code on MySQL for web implementation. Created this in MS-Access for prototype.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using, MySQL, MS SQL Server or MS Access? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: will apply the sql code on mysql for web implementation. just created this for prototype